# Ajax sometimes freezes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

This code is supposed to request new chat messages and append them to the content on my website. The problem, though, is that it sometimes freezes and stops requesting new messages.

```
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/client_message.php?get_message=yes&chat_id=<?php echo $chat_id; ?>&user_id=<?php echo $uid; ?>', 
        success: function(data) {
            content = data;
            if(content != "" && content != prev) {
                $("#chat_wrapper").append(content);
                prev = content;
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
                titleStuff();
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(worker, 700);
        }
    });
})();
```

Please let me know if you need more information to figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: you might try adding an error callback to see if any of the ajax requests are failing.

Comment: And possibly add a timeout so that if it takes longer than x seconds it'l be aborted and retried rather than waiting the full timeout of the browser being used.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: What, if anything, is outputted in the console?

Comment: A weird thing:
As soon as I send a message via Ajax (its a chat function), this ajax code immediately starts requesting new messages again.

This is how I include jQuery and Ajax:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Why are you including two copies of jquery?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

That's the only one I use now.

Comment: Seems like adding this code will do the trick: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this code did the trick:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Seems like the problem was a result of the jQuery cache.